# Expectation values of fermionic operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, fermions, matrix-elements

I'm trying to compute the matrix elements of an Hamiltonian expressed in terms of fermionic operators. The system is an [Agassi](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02834) model, N interacting fermions on 2 levels separated by energy $\epsilon$, where each level contains $\Omega$ degenerate sites.

The Hamiltonian is
$H  = \epsilon J_z - \frac{V}{2}(J_+^2 + J_-^2) - g\sum\limits_{\sigma\sigma'}B_\sigma^\dagger B_{\sigma'}$

where the spin raising/lowering operators can be expressed as

$J^+ = \sum_mc_{1m}^\dagger c_{-1m} = (J^-)^\dagger$

I need to express the matrix elements $\left<n'|H|n\right>$ where $\left|n\right>=\left|J=\frac{N}{2},M=n-J\right>$ is the np-nh many body state corresponding to n particles on the upper level.
Now, I now from basic quantum mechanics the eigenvalues of $J_z$, $J^+$ and $J^-$, for example

$\left<n'|(J^+)^2|n\right> = \sqrt{J(J+1)-M(M+1)}\sqrt{J(J+1)-(M+1)(M+2)}\delta_{n',n+2}$.

My question is: how can I obtain these same results while sticking with the the single fermionic operators? Because for the matrix elements of $B$ and $B^\dagger$ I don't have a direct correspondence with spin operators and I can only work with the fermionic operators. I also know the action of a single fermionic operator, e.g.

$c^\dagger_k\left|n_1n_2...n_k...\right>=(-1)^{\sum\limits_{j<k}n_j}\sqrt{1-n_k}\left|n_1n_2...n_{k+1}...\right>$

but I don't know how to combine this in the sums with different sites and levels to obtain the final result.